# Azure search scale down/suspend

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm having problems with the cost of Azure Search standard level.
Is it possible to change the level of Azure search from standard to Basic? Is it possible to suspend Azure search standard temporarily? I dont see the controls for this in the portal. Do I need to recreate my Azure search implementation as a Basic or Free level to save money?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't change the pricing tier.

Quoting directly from [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-sku-tier/):

> Note: If you underestimate capacity, you will need to provision a new
>   service at the higher tier, and then reload your indexes. There is no
>   in-place upgrade of the same service from one SKU to another.

Comment: The answer is correct. In addition, vote for this [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/12931110-allow-to-upgrade-the-pricing-tier) to help us prioritize in-place SKU changes. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, there is no way to suspend billing on an Azure Search service. You can vote on a related item or open your own here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/10571394-provide-the-ability-to-hibernate-revive-the-index

Comment: 5 years later, neither of the above features is available... and the entire UserVoice site has been taken down.